# pandoc docx output: how to set tables columns width, using a markdown pipe table?

Tags: docx, pandoc

I have this sample input md file

```
| Question | Reply | Note |
| ----- | --- | -- |
|Magna sint duis proident do. Laboris Lorem exercitation consectetur quis|Magna sint duis proident do. Laboris Lorem exercitation consectetur quis|Magna sint duis proident do. Laboris Lorem exercitation consectetur quis|
```

In the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-pipe_tables) I read that the relative cell widths are determined by the number of dashes in the line separating the table header from the table body.

I have `| ----- | --- | -- |`, than it should be 50%, 30% and 20%, but I have a 33, 33, 33 docx output.

The command I use is `pandoc -s input.md -o output.docx` and I’m using `pandoc 2.9.2.1`

Thank you

[image]

---

### Edit - the problem seems to be office365

If I open the same output with LibreOffice, I have the right columns width. But now I have no idea on how to solve it :(

[image]

Comment: We have a pandoc commit to fix it https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/e634d8b87d9fb877658583b03418c23748b70dc5